# nth-child(even) generating ParseException while using jsoup selector in android?

Tags: android, css-selectors, jsoup

Exception:

```
org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'table:nth-child(even)': unexpected token at ':nth-child(even)
```

Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL+params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();  

Elements questions= doc.select(".content-box table:nth-child(even) a");
```

content-box is a class name of div.
What is wrong with `nth-child()` method in jsoup?

`nth-child()` is working in http://try.jsoup.org/ site, but it making an exception while using in Android.

Logcat:

```
W/System.err(2280): org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'table:nth-child(even)': unexpected token at ':nth-child(even)'
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.findElements(QueryParser.java:170)    
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:63)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:37)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.combinator(QueryParser.java:79)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:59)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:37)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:66)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:79)
W/System.err(2280):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(Element.java:255)
W/System.err(2280):     at com.example1.MainScreen$MyTask.doInBackground(MainScreen.java:80)
W/System.err(2280):     at com.example1.MainScreen$MyTask.doInBackground(MainScreen.java:1)
W/System.err(2280):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err(2280):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err(2280):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err(2280):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(2280):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(2280):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Can you post the site's URL? Are you sure that you're getting the exect same result at your browser and at your app? Are you modifing the app's `UserAgent`?

Comment: URL: (http://putlocker.is/search/search.php?q=spider%20man), I am getting two different results in browser and the app. In browser (http://try.jsoup.org/) I am getting all anchor tags, but in app getting nothing but Exception. UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36

Comment: Can you add the code for downloading the page?

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL+params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36").referrer("http://www.google.com").get();

Comment: It works for me. I've tried your code (in a `AsyncTask`) and got results like `<a href="http://putlocker.is/watch-the-amazing-spider-man-2-online-free-putlocker-552120.html" title="The Amazing Spider-Man 2 (2014)"><b>The Amazing Spider-M..</b></a>`, `<a href="http://putlocker.is/watch-the-amazing-spider-man-2-online-free-putlocker-552120.html" title="The Amazing Spider-Man 2 (2014)"><img src="http://image6.putlocker.is/images/covers/the-amazing-spider-man-2-online-free-putlocker-552120.jpg" border="0" style="padding:1px;border:1px solid silver;" alt="The Amazing Spider-Man 2"></a>`

Comment: No idea why that would fail only on Android, but does `table:nth-child(2n)` instead of `table:nth-child(even)` work for you?

Comment: Nope. Here the problem with :nth-child() method. Consider this issue (https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/197)

Comment: Now it is working, After I updated jsuoup.jar file (http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.8.2.jar). I believe it is problem with old version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by OP:

> Now it is working, After I updated jsuoup.jar file (jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.8.2.jar). I believe it is problem with old version.